# Can I paginate a custom query without overriding the default pagination?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pagination, having

In my CakePHP (1.2) app, I have two actions that both use pagination - index and search.

In a previous question I learnt that, in order to apply a threshold score to search results, I need to use the `HAVING` MySQL keyword. Since CakePHP does not support this natively, I need to drop down to a custom query in order to accomplish this.

All the guides I can find to custom query pagination involve overriding the `paginate()` and `paginateCount()` methods.

Since I still want to be able to paginate normally on the index however, I don't want to change the normal pagination behaviour in the model.

Is there any way I can (ahem) have my Cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually if you CAN do it with find you CAN do it with paginate. You can take a look [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/165/Controller-Setup)

But to be more especific you can add the conditions/limit/fields/contain/order etc that you use in find to the paginate function.

I haven't use group in the paginate but it SHOULD work :D

In your case you will have something like this:

```
$this->paginate = array(
   'fields' => array(
        'Product.category_id',
        'COUNT(Product.hotel_id) as total'
    ),
   'group' => array(
        'Product.category_id HAVING COUNT(Product.hotel_id) > 1')
    )
);

$data = $this->paginate('Product');
```

Hope it works, post a comment of your result, if it doesn't work you will have to override it, because it is not accepting the group condition... though I think it will work since pagination is a find in the end.

EDIT:

You may try to do something like this:

Override the paginate() and paginateCount() but with a tweak, sneak a condition so you can tell if its a pagination with having or not. Something like this:

```
function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page = 1, $recursive = null, $extra = array()){
   //if no having conditions set return the parent paginate 
   if (empty($conditions['having'])
       return parent::paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page, $recursive, $extra)
   //if having conditions set return your override

//override code here

}
```

Then you do something similar in paginateCount(), that way you have a selective paginate. remember to do unset $conditions['having'] once it is not needed or remember to put it somewhere that doesn't affect your find ;)

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but unfortunately breaks paginateCount() because of the lack of column called "score".

Comment: +1 For sneaking the `HAVING` clause in the group by string. But when you're copypasting, take care of those hideous curly quotes.

Comment: sorry for that, thanks for the edit
@TomWright Hmmmm, that's true, i suppose, you have to override the paginateCount() function, reading a little bit more of custom query in [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/249/Custom-Query-Pagination) i see that indeed you need to override at least the paginateCount(); BUT you can do something to differentiate which to use, i explain this sugestion at the bottom of my answer

Comment: Thanks api55. I've marked this as correct because it's obviously the correct approach, but it seems to have caused a weird problem. See my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7583307/50151

Answer (score 1):

Actually getting this to work was more of a headache than you might reasonably expect.

Although I basically followed the advice of api55 (thanks!) I also jumped a load of other hurdles:

- It's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583307/why-does-cakephp-use-this-method-name-in-a-mysql-query-rather-than-return-the-res) to do `parent::paginateCount()`. I overcame this by overriding it with a [different (and apparently better) version](http://www.mainelydesign.com/blog/view/best-paginatecount-cakephp-with-group-by-support) in app_model.php.
- Because `paginateCount()` is just a wrapper for `find('count')`, it doesn't accept a `fields` parameter. This is tricky for me as I rely on this to squeeze in my derived column (score of a full-text search). I got over this by passing the value of `fields` twice to `paginate` - once as `fields` and once as "`sneaky`". Cake puts any parameters it doesn't recognize into the `extra` array.
- Tying this together, I had an override of `paginateCount()` in my model that looks to see whether `extra` has an key called "sneaky". If it does, it does a `find('all')` and uses the contents of `sneaky` to populate fields.

It's days like today that I have to step back and remember all the good points about using a framework.