# Pagination strategy in existing cakephp application

Tags: cakephp, pagination

**The Problem:**
I have designed my models and controllers across my application without keeping cakePhp's inbuilt pagination in mind.

Consider the simplification of my index method in the Announcements Controller:

```
public function index($room_id) {
    $this->set('room_id', $room_id);

    $tiles = $this->Announcement->getAnnouncementTiles($room_id);
    $this->set('tiles', $tiles);
}
```

The model method that does a simple find

```
protected function getAnnouncements($room_id) {

    $options['contain'] = array();
    $options['conditions'] = array(
        'room_id' => $room_id
    );
    $data = $this->find('all', $options);

    return $data;
}
```

The model method that manipulates data from getAnnouncements, and is called by the controller.

```
public function getAnnouncementTiles($room_id) {
    $datadump = $this->getAnnouncements($room_id);

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($datadump as $data) {
        $tiles[$i]['subject'] = $data['Announcement']['subject'];
        $tiles[$i]['name'] = $this->AppUser->getFullName($data['Announcement']['user_id']);
        $tiles[$i]['body'] = $data['Announcement']['body'];
        $tiles[$i]['created'] = $data['Announcement']['created'];
        $i++;
    }
    return $tiles;
}
```

**Question:** So basically I have controllers that call several model methods to manipulate data, that ultimately comes from a simple find call. What strategy should I follow to keep my pagination code simple (avoiding complexity of handling it myself by implementing `paginate()`, `paginateCount()` etc. If i need to re-factor my code, how? Should I convert this to a custom find type?

Comment: Your function getAnnouncementTiles is just reformatting your data so that it no longer is using the standard CakePHP format.  If there's no particular reason to do this, I think it is better to not change the standard CakePHP format, since it'll probably get you into trouble, juggling the CakePHP format, and whatever format you've come up with.  If however, you do want to consistently change your data to that format after all, move your code for getAnnouncementTiles to the model's afterFind function.  You may need to change it some to work in afterFind, but it should affect find and paginate.

Comment: @kai thanks for the feedback. I will asses the models and see if its a trivial change of format. So is converting to a custom or simple find the only way to use pagination out of the box?

Comment: You can also rewrite the model's paginate and paginateCount functions.  I think that works the best for those cases where you're trying to paginate some results that are really close to what paginate expects, but it doesn't quite work without a little tweaking.  For example, this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569910/can-i-paginate-a-custom-query-without-overriding-the-default-pagination

Comment: @Kai So yes, it's tricky. I have to examine if this applies in 2.x also. What about lazy loading pagination? For that I would have to any way settle for a custom strategy?

Comment: @Kai I guess it will be the same pagination strategy, in a ajax call.

Comment: I've written minor changes to paginate and paginateCount in 2.x.  I don't think paginate has changed all that much, at least up to 2.3.  I've just been giving general advice, but it sounds like you have something specific in mind, so I think you need to be more specific regarding what you're looking for.  But I have made infinite-scrolling pages by using paginate plus an infinite scrolling jquery plugin, if that's the kind of thing you're looking for.  http://www.netboy.pl/2010/06/infinite-scroll-cakephp/

Comment: @Kai Thankyou. No, I was investigating strategies to paginate without messing around with existing code, and without missing the benefits of cakePhp's pagination. I'm investigating stuff you've shared.